# ko is undefined error when using requirejs for knockout and knockout.simpleGrid

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, amd, knockout-3.0

I'm getting ko is undefined error in knockout.simpleGrid 3.0 when using requirejs to load dependencies. Here is my require.config.js

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        "bootstrap": "Scripts/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap",
        "crossroads": "Scripts/lib/crossroads/crossroads",
        "jquery": "Scripts/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.4",
        "knockout": "Scripts/lib/knockout/knockout-3.3.0",
        "koSimpleGrid": "Scripts/lib/knockout/knockout.simpleGrid.3.0",
        "koProjections": "Scripts/lib/knockout/knockout-projections",
        "signals": "Scripts/lib/crossroads/signals",
        "hasher": "Scripts/lib/crossroads/hasher",
        "text": "Scripts/lib/require/text"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": { deps: ["jquery"] },
        "koSimpleGrid": { deps: ["knockout"] }
    }
}
```

here is the code which is causing the error.

```
 ko.simpleGrid = {
        // Defines a view model class you can use to populate a grid
        viewModel: function (configuration) {
            this.data = configuration.data;
            this.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(0);
            this.pageSize = configuration.pageSize || 5;

            // If you don't specify columns configuration, we'll use scaffolding
            this.columns = configuration.columns || getColumnsForScaffolding(ko.unwrap(this.data));

            this.itemsOnCurrentPage = ko.computed(function () {
                var startIndex = this.pageSize * this.currentPageIndex();
                return ko.unwrap(this.data).slice(startIndex, startIndex + this.pageSize);
            }, this);

            this.maxPageIndex = ko.computed(function () {
                return Math.ceil(ko.unwrap(this.data).length / this.pageSize) - 1;
            }, this);
        }
    };
```

I tried passing the ko as parameter to knockout.simpleGrid but still it gives the same error on this line

```
this.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(0);
```

Comment: make sure your are referring knockout js correctly .

Comment: Its referenced in other js files too. And working correctly

Comment: Could be this:
https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/259